# vs tfs 2012 empty pending changes

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I worked some hours when tfs server was unavailabe. After go online and getted new sources I have 1900 files with empty pending changes plus my 10 files with really pending changes. It is possible to undo only empty pending changes by several cclicks or some script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to undo changes when there are some, you will be warned; when there aren't any, it'll silently succeed. Similarly, if you try to commit a "no change", the file history doesn't update, and your file is no longer checked out. Therefore you've two options:

1. Try an "undo all" and cancel the undo on the files you want to keep the changes in.
2. Commit the unchanged files alongside your changed ones. And have them silently undo. (of course, if you do code reviews, your reviewer might not like you for this)

Comment: I really loathe the "undo all" and cancel approach because it's an errant keystroke away from losing your data.

Comment: @EdwardThomson me too, which is why I mentioned the null check in option, but circumstances will vary as to which is the "better" option

Comment: My distinct preference is `tfpt uu`, but I realize there's no analog in the Visual Studio UI, so I do appreciate what you're saying.

Comment: Yes, Edward, it script I was looking for

Use the TFS power tools. Open a visual studio command prompt, navigate to your workspace and then type

tfpt uu /noget /recursive

This will undo any pending changes on files that haven't been modified

When invoking TFPT you might get one of the errors:
Unable to determine the workspace

Unable to determine the source control server

 

To get around this try invoking tfpt from within a directory that is already mapped to Team Foundation source control.